# C structure is not passing correct parameters to pthread_create

Tags: c

I am building a Suduko Solution Validator in C that must use 27 threads to check each row, column, and subgrid for repeating numbers. Currently, my threads for rows and columns correctly check their respective areas. However, the subgrid array check fails.I believe it is failing because somewhere it is getting the wrong parameters.  Below is some of my code

```
typedef struct index
{
int topRow;
int bottomRow;
int leftColumn;
int rightColumn;

}indexParam;

int main()
{
int i,j;
//Initialize subgrids
struct index subgridArray[9];
for(i=0;i<9;i=i+3)
{
    for(j=0;j<9;j=j+3)
    {
        subgridArray[i].topRow = i;
        printf("top row %d, ", subgridArray[i].topRow);
        subgridArray[i].bottomRow = i+2;
        printf("bottom row %d, ", subgridArray[i].bottomRow);
        subgridArray[i].leftColumn = j;
        printf("left col %d, ", subgridArray[i].leftColumn);
        subgridArray[i].rightColumn = j+2;
        printf("right col %d \n", subgridArray[i].rightColumn);
    }
    
 }
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    printf("Top row: %d, Bottom Row: %d, Left Column: %d, right Column: %d\n", subgridArray[i].topRow, subgridArray[i].bottomRow, subgridArray[i].leftColumn, subgridArray[i].rightColumn);
}
//Create worker threads for subgrids
for(i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    pthread_create(&tid_Subgrid[i], NULL, subgridChecker, &(subgridArray[i]));
    printf("%d I am subgrid thread %d: ,my bounds are: %d, %d, %d,%d\n",i, tid_Subgrid[i],subgridArray[i].topRow,subgridArray[i].bottomRow, subgridArray[i].leftColumn, subgridArray[i].rightColumn);
}
```

While initializing the Subgrid, the print statements correctly print the index parameters.

```
top row 0, bottom row 2, left col 0, right col 2
top row 0, bottom row 2, left col 3, right col 5
top row 0, bottom row 2, left col 6, right col 8
top row 3, bottom row 5, left col 0, right col 2
top row 3, bottom row 5, left col 3, right col 5
top row 3, bottom row 5, left col 6, right col 8
top row 6, bottom row 8, left col 0, right col 2
top row 6, bottom row 8, left col 3, right col 5 
top row 6, bottom row 8, left col 6, right col 8
```

The next for loop where I print out the contents of the subgrid array produces incorrect output

```
Top row: 0, Bottom Row: 2, Left Column: 6, right Column: 8
Top row: 4194304, Bottom Row: 0, Left Column: 112, right Column: 0
Top row: 7148784, Bottom Row: 0, Left Column: 0, right Column: 0
Top row: 3, Bottom Row: 5, Left Column: 6, right Column: 8
Top row: -360710144, Bottom Row: 3217425, Left Column: 5, right Column: 0
Top row: 0, Bottom Row: 0, Left Column: 0, right Column: 0
Top row: 6, Bottom Row: 8, Left Column: 6, right Column: 8
Top row: 4194304, Bottom Row: 0, Left Column: 81920, right Column: 0
Top row: 112, Bottom Row: 0, Left Column: 11141288, right Column: 0
```

The function that each thread works on also outputs incorrect parameters and only 5 threads print out rather than the 9 required. I am a noob when it comes to C so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're only initializing 3 of the 9 structures in that array. The index `[i]` doesn't change when `j` changes. Perhaps you meant `[i + j/3]`. Another option is to have a separate index `k` that is incremented at the end of the `j` loop.

Comment: If you want a 3x3 matrix I recommend you do it the easy and simple way first: Using an array of arrays. As in `struct index subgridArray[3][3];`

Comment: BTW, using 27 threads is unlikely to make things faster, unless you have a monster machine with 32 cores. You would be better off creating three threads, one for rows, one for columns, and one for sub grids. I'm assuming you have a typical machine with 4 cores.

Comment: Just curious: what do you do if the first thread on its first check finds out that the grid is invalid? Keep going on all 26 threads to their end?

Comment: @user3386109 your solution worked. As for your other question, I was required to use 27 threads. Performance was not taken into consideration.

Comment: @HenryGray Glad to hear the solution worked. But sometimes I gotta wonder what they're teaching in schools these days. Perhaps they expect that by the time you graduate, everyone will have a 32 core machine :)